# How does shuffling trigger?

Tags: nerts-online

Sometimes in [Nerts!](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1131190/NERTS_Online/), everyone's deck gets shuffled (at the same time) and the announcer's voice calls out 'Shuffle!'.  None of us could figure out what triggers this though.  Sometimes I'm stuck with a deck that isn't doing much for me and would like to shuffle but it seems random.

What triggers a shuffle?

Comment: There is a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerts) on Nerts (I assume the steam game follows its rules) and the only mention of shuffling is "_After the cards are returned, the decks are shuffled and set up for the next hand and the process is repeated until a player wins_"

Comment: Nah there is a shuffle that happens periodically during the game.  My best guess is it happens when the game determines that everyone is 'stuck' but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: out of curiosity I checked the steam page and someone claimed that "it happens 60 seconds after a card was last moved to the foundations in the centre of the screen" - should be easy enough to check